# Issue with applying customize buttons to Slick JS slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I apply customize buttons to Slick Slider JS. I am having a problem with applying my very own button styles to the slider. I want to use arrow icons instead of the default buttons.

HTML:

```
<section id="testimonial"> <!-- Testimonial section -->
    <div class="slider"> 
      <div><img src="img/testimonial-1.png" alt="Testimonial from Bartholomew Watson of Abicord Consulting"></div>  
      <div><img src="img/testimonial-2.png" alt="Testimonial from Dwayne Ferguson of CC Collect"></div>
      <div><img src="img/testimonial-3.png" alt="Testimonial from David Jamilly of Kindness UK"></div>
      <div><img src="img/testimonial-4.png" alt="Testimonial from Sergey Slepov of Credit Suisse"></div>
    </div>
   </section>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.slider').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1, 
        slidesToScroll: 1, 
        autoplay: true, 
        autoplaySpeed: 2000
      });
});
```

CSS:

```
.slick-next {
 background: url('../img/right-arrow.png') no-repeat;
}
.slick-prev {
 background: url('../img/left-arrow.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom arrows by adding these to your JS:

```
$('.slider').slick({
    arrows: true,
    prevArrow: '<div class="slick-prev"></div>',
    nextArrow: '<div class="slick-next"></div>'
}
```

That will drop divs with these classes into the DOM and you can style as needed.

---

Or, instead of above, you can modify the existing buttons:

```
.slick-next {
    background: url('../img/right-arrow.png') no-repeat !important;
}
.slick-prev {
    background: url('../img/left-arrow.png') no-repeat !important;
}
.slick-next::before, .slick-prev::before {
    content: "" !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes the default buttons disappear. The customise arrows seem to be hidden?

Comment: Question for you - were your classes originally missing the period in front of them? The first part of my answer was to add custom arrows, but it occurred to me that it might have been just a minor css error.

Comment: No originally I had the period in front, by mistake I paste the code onto here without the period sorry. With your suggestion the default buttons have gone but there no show of the png custom arrows.

Comment: Do they show in the inspector? You'll need some more CSS as they are custom now.

Comment: Yes in inspector this what shows in: HTML: <div  class ="slick-next.slick-arrow" style="display: block;"></div>  CSS: .slick-next {
    background: url('../img/right-arrow.png') no-repeat;
}

Comment: I modified the second part of my answer - that might be more helpful.